# FCM handles IOS notification when app is foreground which is I do not want to

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

I use fcm and local_notifications for handling push notifications on my **Flutter** project.

Sending notifications using this payload:

```
{
  token: body.token,
  notification = {
      title: body.data.title,
      body: body.data.body,
  },
  data: {
      data: JSON.stringify(body.data),
  }
}
```

So when notification comes

**on app terminated:** Notification shows up perfectly for both app(ios - android)

**on app background:** Notification shows up perfectly for both app(ios - android)

**on app foreground:**

*android app:* notification comes like a data notification, fcm is not alerting anything as I want it.

*ios app:* when the notification comes, fcm is displaying an alert which is I do not want to. And also local_notifications is displaying at the same time.

**My problem is fcm handles foreground notifications on ios app. When it works that way I can't disable the notification that should not appear on foreground.**

**pubspec.yaml:**

```
firebase_messaging: ^10.0.4
flutter_local_notifications: ^8.1.1+1
```

**firebase foreground notification options:**

```
await instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);
```

> When I remove firebase foreground notification options or set false all parameters, local_notifications can't display any notifications too.

**local_notifications foreground notification options:**

```
instance.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()?.requestPermissions(
          alert: true,
          badge: true,
          sound: true,
        );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:
It was too obvious :D

```
await instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(alert: false, badge: true, sound: true);
```

alert parameter should be false if you do not want FCM to handle foreground alers.